# why javascript code changed the innerText,while the page dosen't?

Tags: javascript, html, innertext

> purpose:I know js-DOM can change the innerText; i want every online  user can see the data I chenged.

In an online page,I want to change  the

```html
 <span> old  text</span>
```

,to

```html
 <span> new  text</span>
```

。
 So ,I set the

```html
 span.innerText ='new text'
```

through the console with javscript codes,and the current page is what i want .(page shows 'new text').
**But,but,but**,when I reflesh the browser/ reload the page --> page shows 'old text'.it  means my innerText setting doesnot work?
 **Question:**
1 why it happens?  because the js didnot post the data to the service?
2 how to handle it ?

Comment: You should definitely refer to this [ask].

Comment: First you have to get it's `DOM` or instance then change its' inner html

Comment: When you refresh the browser, the code is resent to you from the server, as it was originally, without the changes you made. You can change the code, and try to run it client-side with the changes you made, in order to afterwards post to the server. Try reading on the client/server html model for more info. I would recommend trying https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/

Comment: Thank you.   I was through DOM changed the innerText.  I think I should learn more about the client/server html model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, earn your element control then change it :

```js
const span = document.querySelector('span');
span.textContent='new text';
```

Comment: and  then  reload your page , all hasnot  changed .

Comment: I know how to use js change the text,but I dont know ,reopen your page ,the data you had changed ,is still there?

Comment: if your goal is to see it(new text) after reopening explorer, you can save it in explorer local storage something like this.

Comment: it is a online page. I want to all the user can see new text ,not only me ,  different user,different device.  how to do ? THANK YOU

Comment: So, you have to save it in the DataBase

Answer (score 0):

Just give the container an identity so that you can operate on it...

```
<span id="Test"> old  text</span>
```

Now you can manipulate it...

```
Test.innerText ='new text';
```

Comment: I want other user open the page , he can also see the  'new text'. how to do ?thank you

Comment: Study how to store things and retrieve them... https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp